# How to show progress in cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I use code in `didSelectRowAt indexPath:` to start download file on cell click and I use code in `cellForRowAt indexPath:` to show progress of now downloading files.

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return (mainArray[buttonIndex] as AnyObject).count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(format: "cell", indexPath.row), for: indexPath)
        let circularProgressViewForCell = FFCircularProgressView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(24), height: CGFloat(24)))
        cell.accessoryView = circularProgressViewForCell
        circularProgressViewForCell.isHidden = true

        DownloadManager.shared.onProgress = { (progress) in
        circularProgressViewForCell.isHidden = false
        OperationQueue.main.addOperation {
            circularProgressViewForCell.progress = CGFloat(progress)
            if (cell.accessoryView as! FFCircularProgressView?)?.progress == 1.0 {
                print("FFCircularProgressView")
                (cell.accessoryView as! FFCircularProgressView?)?.circularState = .completed
            }
        }
    }
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let url = URL(string: "link")!
    let downloadTaskLocal =  DownloadManager.shared.activate().downloadTask(with: url)
    downloadTaskLocal.resume()
}
}
```

I create URLSession in `DownloadManager`:

```
import Foundation

class DownloadManager : NSObject, URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionDownloadDelegate {

    static var shared = DownloadManager()

    typealias ProgressHandler = (Float) -> ()

    var onProgress : ProgressHandler? {
        didSet {
            if onProgress != nil {
                let _ = activate()
            }
        }
    }

    override private init() {
        super.init()
    }

    func activate() -> URLSession {
        let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "\(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!).background")


        return URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue())
    }

    private func calculateProgress(session : URLSession, completionHandler : @escaping (Float) -> ()) {
        session.getTasksWithCompletionHandler { (tasks, uploads, downloads) in
            let progress = downloads.map({ (task) -> Float in
                if task.countOfBytesExpectedToReceive > 0 {
                    return Float(task.countOfBytesReceived) / Float(task.countOfBytesExpectedToReceive)
                } else {
                    return 0.0
                }
            })
            completionHandler(progress.reduce(0.0, +))
        }
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                    downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask,
                    didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL){

        let fileName = downloadTask.originalRequest?.url?.lastPathComponent
        let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
        let documentDirectoryPath:String = path[0]
        let fileManager = FileManager()
        var destinationURLForFile = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectoryPath.appending("/\(id)"))
        do {
            try fileManager.createDirectory(at: destinationURLForFile, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            destinationURLForFile.appendPathComponent(String(describing: fileName!))
            try fileManager.moveItem(at: location, to: destinationURLForFile)
        }catch(let error){
            print(error)
        }

    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {

        if totalBytesExpectedToWrite > 0 {
            if let onProgress = onProgress {
                calculateProgress(session: session, completionHandler: onProgress)
            }
            let progress = Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
            debugPrint("Progress \(downloadTask) \(progress)")

        }
    }

    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
        debugPrint("Task completed: \(task), error: \(error)")
    }

}
```

I want to click on cell, start file download and show progress of downloading file in selected cell. I can create my progressView in `didSelectRowAt indexPath:` but it is not the best solution because user may move on previous or next controller in my app or may hide app when downloading is active. And when user returns in TableViewController I update progress in `cellForRowAt indexPath:`.

Problem: when I start downloading file my progress not display in selected row. Progress display in row outside the screen. And when I scroll tableView I see changing of progress in all cells. How to fix it and show progress in selected cell?

UPD

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

                    var item = self.items[indexPath.row]
                    if item.downloadStatus == .inProgress || item.downloadStatus == .completed {
                        print("video already downloaded")
                    }
                    else {
                        let url = URL(string: "link\(indexPath.row)")!

                        let int = self.tableId + indexPath.row // table0 = 1000, table1 = 2000 and etc.

                        DownloadManager.shared.identifier = int
                        let downloadTaskLocal =  DownloadManager.shared.activate().downloadTask(with: url)
                        downloadTaskLocal.resume()

                        DownloadManager.shared.onProgress = { (row, progress) in

                            var row = row
                            row = row - self.tableId


                            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                let indexpath = IndexPath.init(row: row, section: 0)
                                let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexpath)
                                print("downloading for cell \(String(describing: cell?.tag))")
                                if progress <= 1.0 {

                                    let progressRing = cell?.accessoryView as! FFCircularProgressView
                                    progressRing.progress = CGFloat(progress)

                                    if progress == 1.0 {
                                        item.downloadStatus = .completed
                                        cell?.textLabel?.text = "Download Complete"
                                    }
                                    else {
                                        cell?.textLabel?.text = "Download In Progress"
                                    }

                                }
                            }



}
```

**UPD 1**

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit

enum DownloadStatus {
    case none
    case inProgress
    case completed
    case failed
}
struct item {
    var title : String!
    let link = ""
    var downloadStatus : DownloadStatus = .none

    init(title: String) {
        self.title = title
    }
}

var id = ""

class MasterViewController: UITableViewController {

    var mainArray:[[Any]] = []
    var index = 0
    var buttonIndex = 0
    var objects = [Any]()
    var items = [item]()
    var tableId = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

            items.append(item(title: "Video 1"))
            items.append(item(title: "Video 2"))
            items.append(item(title: "Video 3"))
            items.append(item(title: "Video 4"))
            items.append(item(title: "Video 5"))
            items.append(item(title: "Video 6"))
            items.append(item(title: "Video 7"))
            items.append(item(title: "Video 8"))
            items.append(item(title: "Video 9"))
            items.append(item(title: "Video 10"))
            items.append(item(title: "Video 11"))
            items.append(item(title: "Video 12"))

        if buttonIndex == 0 {
            id = "id0"
            tableId = 1000
        }
        else if buttonIndex == 1 {
            id = "id1"
            tableId = 2000
        }

        mainArray = [array0,array1,array2,array3,array4,array5,array6]

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(self.onApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification), name: NSNotification.Name.UIApplicationDidBecomeActive, object: nil)

    }

    func onApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification(notification:Notification) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return (mainArray[buttonIndex] as AnyObject).count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: String(format: "cell", indexPath.row), for: indexPath)

        let item = items[indexPath.row]

        print(item.downloadStatus)

        if item.downloadStatus != .completed {
            let progressRing = FFCircularProgressView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 24, height: 24))
            cell.tag = indexPath.row
            cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.none
            cell.accessoryView = progressRing
        }
        else {
            cell.accessoryView = nil
        }

        return cell
    }



    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

                        var item = self.items[indexPath.row]
                        if item.downloadStatus == .inProgress || item.downloadStatus == .completed {
                            print("video already downloaded")
                        }
                        else {
                            let url = URL(string: "link\(indexPath.row + 1).mp3")!
                            let int = self.tableId + indexPath.row
                            let downloadManager = DownloadManager()
                            downloadManager.identifier = int
                            downloadManager.folderPath = id
                            let downloadTaskLocal =  downloadManager.activate().downloadTask(with: url)
                            downloadTaskLocal.resume()


                             downloadManager.onProgress = { (row, progress) in

                                var row = row
                                row = row - self.tableId

                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    let indexpath = IndexPath.init(row: row, section: 0)
                                    let cell = self.tableView.cellForRow(at: indexpath)
                                    print("downloading for cell \(String(describing: cell?.tag))")
                                    if progress <= 1.0 {

                                        let progressRing = FFCircularProgressView(frame: CGRect(x: CGFloat(0), y: CGFloat(0), width: CGFloat(24), height: CGFloat(24)))
                                        cell?.accessoryView = progressRing
                                        progressRing.progress = CGFloat(progress)

                                        if progress == 1.0 {
                                            item.downloadStatus = .completed
                                        }

                                    }


    }               
    }
}
```

Code from FirstViewController

```
import UIKit
import StoreKit

class TableViewController: UITableViewController {

    let array = ["","","","","","",""]


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        let newBackButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: .plain, target: nil, action: nil)
        self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = newBackButton
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {

        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return array.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        cell.button.tag = indexPath.row

        cell.selectionStyle = .none

        return cell
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
    {

        return 165.0
    }

    public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
        return 12.0
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView?
    {
        let headerView = UIView()
            headerView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        return headerView
    }

    // MARK: - Navigation

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if (segue.destination is MasterViewController) {
            if let button = sender as? UIButton {
                (segue.destination as? MasterViewController)?.buttonIndex = button.tag
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Code from TableViewCell

```
import UIKit

class TableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)


    }

}
```

Comment: look at this link https://www.raywenderlich.com/158106/urlsession-tutorial-getting-started   You would get pause, cancel, resume in download option.

Comment: You need to pass the indexpath row to DownloadManager and return the value to cell through ProgressHandler along with progress value. In cell, compare the indexpath row values and display the progress bar. this will show the progress only in downloading cell.

Comment: @Basheer Yes! I've been trying to do this for a few days, but I do not know how to do it correctly. Could you add some code to your answer and show me how to do this?

Comment: @Artem i have done the suggestion code changes and updated as answer. pls check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Artem I have added a property in DownloadManager, as 'identifier' (int). This will save the indexpath.row value.

Send this identifier value back in ProgressHandler completion block.

Attached the updated code with above changes.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath)


        DownloadManager.shared.onProgress = { (row, progress) in
            print("Downloading for \(row) with progress \(progress)")
        }

        return cell
    }



override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        let url = URL(string: "link")!
        DownloadManager.shared.identifier = indexPath.row
        let downloadTaskLocal =  DownloadManager.shared.activate().downloadTask(with: url)
        downloadTaskLocal.resume()
    }
```

In your DownloadManager,

class DownloadManager : NSObject, URLSessionDelegate, URLSessionDownloadDelegate {

```
static var shared = DownloadManager()
var identifier : Int = -1
typealias ProgressHandler = (Int, Float) -> ()

var onProgress : ProgressHandler? {
    didSet {
        if onProgress != nil {
            let _ = activate()
        }
    }
}

override private init() {
    super.init()
}

func activate() -> URLSession {
    let config = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "\(Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!).background")


    return URLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: OperationQueue())
}

private func calculateProgress(session : URLSession, completionHandler : @escaping (Int, Float) -> ()) {
    session.getTasksWithCompletionHandler { (tasks, uploads, downloads) in
        let progress = downloads.map({ (task) -> Float in
            if task.countOfBytesExpectedToReceive > 0 {
                return Float(task.countOfBytesReceived) / Float(task.countOfBytesExpectedToReceive)
            } else {
                return 0.0
            }
        })
        completionHandler(self.identifier, progress.reduce(0.0, +))
    }
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask,
                didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL){

    let fileName = downloadTask.originalRequest?.url?.lastPathComponent
    let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
    let documentDirectoryPath:String = path[0]
    let fileManager = FileManager()
    var destinationURLForFile = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectoryPath.appending("/\(id)"))
    do {
        try fileManager.createDirectory(at: destinationURLForFile, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
        destinationURLForFile.appendPathComponent(String(describing: fileName!))
        try fileManager.moveItem(at: location, to: destinationURLForFile)
    }catch(let error){
        print(error)
    }

}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {

    if totalBytesExpectedToWrite > 0 {
        if let onProgress = onProgress {
            calculateProgress(session: session, completionHandler: onProgress)
        }
        let progress = Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)
        debugPrint("Progress \(downloadTask) \(progress)")

    }
}

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, task: URLSessionTask, didCompleteWithError error: Error?) {
    debugPrint("Task completed: \(task), error: \(String(describing: error))")


   }

}
```

**UPDATED ANSWER**

I have created a simple project to demonstrate the download progress update on UITableViewCell.

https://github.com/mcabasheer/table-cell-progress-bar/tree/master

[image]

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thank you very much! You saved my time! Could you check please it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45863304/save-file-in-folder

Comment: I have some problems. When I move between controllers progress not show. but this condition works `if item.downloadStatus != .completed {`

Comment: Why can it be??

Comment: @Artem when you load the cell, are you showing the progress bar based on the item.downloadStatus flag?  when you move to new controller and come back, what is the status of this flag?

Comment: item.downloadStatus none... in all cases in `cellForRowAt indexPath:`

Comment: then your progress data is lost. are you initialising your model on view did appear?

Comment: I have this `override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }`

Comment: when you move to new controller and navigate back to table view with progress bar, what you are doing with the item model objects?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153009/discussion-between-basheer-and-artem).

Answer (score 0):

The problem in your case is the reuse of cells.
In `tableView(: cellForRowAt:)` you must manage the fact that user is downloading from concrete cell, not downloading at all.
It seems that your DownloadManager doesn't know from which url (cell) you're downloading.
For example keep the array of selected urls.

Comment: I've been trying to do this for a few days, but I do not know how to do it. Could you add some code to your answer and show me how to do this?

Comment: Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

For progressive download and showing that to tableview, you have to follow these steps,

**Step 1** : When cell clicked, store it's index in an array. (Let's name that array - `arrDownloads`)

**Step 2** : In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` check if `arrDownloads` contains current index path

**Step 3** : If current index In `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is inside `arrDownloads` then pass URL of current index to Download Manager. (Make sure you have another array of URLs to download images(files))

[This](http://sweettutos.com/2015/12/31/swift-how-to-asynchronously-download-and-cache-images-without-relying-on-third-party-libraries/) may help.

Comment: It is not help me. I think that you not understand my question. I need to show progress in selected cell. I should pass number of selected cell in `cellForRowAt indexPath:` or `DownloadManager `. How to do it?

Comment: @ can't do this because I create link in `didSelectRowAt indexPath:` like: `let url = URL(string: "link\(indexPath.row)")!`

Answer (score 0):

I Think, you set your progress in header of tableView. You can see your progress when scrolling tableview.

Comment: It is not help me. I think that you not understand my question. I need to show progress in selected cell. I need to pass the indexpath row to DownloadManager and return the value to cell through ProgressHandler along with progress value. In cell, compare the indexpath row values and display the progress bar . How to do it?