# Save file in folder

Tags: ios, swift

I have `ViewController` with cells. If user click on one of cells he go in next `TableController` with id(tableNumber). In `TableController` user can download files.

Problem: When user download file in first tableView(id1) return in ViewController and go in second tableView(id2) files after downloading save in one folder like this: `/Documents/id2`. But I need in this case save the files like this: first file `/Documents/id1` second file `/Documents/id2`. How to do it?

code in `TableController` to pass id in `DownloadManager`:

```
DownloadManager.shared.id = self.id
```

code in `DownloadManager` to save file:

```
var id = ""

func urlSession(_ session: URLSession,
                    downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask,
                    didFinishDownloadingTo location: URL){

        let fileName = downloadTask.originalRequest?.url?.lastPathComponent
        let path = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(FileManager.SearchPathDirectory.documentDirectory, FileManager.SearchPathDomainMask.userDomainMask, true)
        let documentDirectoryPath:String = path[0]
        let fileManager = FileManager()
        var destinationURLForFile = URL(fileURLWithPath: documentDirectoryPath.appending("/\(id)"))
        do {
            try fileManager.createDirectory(at: destinationURLForFile, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)
            destinationURLForFile.appendPathComponent(String(describing: fileName!))
            try fileManager.moveItem(at: location, to: destinationURLForFile)
        }catch(let error){
            print(error)
        }

    }
```

Comment: @matt I wrote this in question. My files save in one folder. But I need save in two folders, when user download several files.

Comment: @matt Why should I save one folder in another? I have 5 table IDs? I need to save files from tables into 5 different folders(IDs). When I download 5 different  files from 5 different tables, the files are saved only to the one folder(last id). But I ned to save in 5 different folders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For every download, create an instance of DownloadManager and download the videos.

You can create a variable to save folder path, row/table id in DownloadManager.

Since you are creating new instance for DownloadManager for each download, you can have different folder path defined for each view controller and row/table id.

After file is downloaded, use the above variables to save files in folder.

Don't use `DownloadManager.shared.`

Use `DownloadManager()`

Hope this helps :)

Comment: I trying to pass table id at global variable but this don't work too. And If I use this `var downloadManager = DownloadManager()` I get `'DownloadManager' initializer is inaccessible due to 'private' protection level`

Comment: Your DownloadManager init() method has private keyword. Remove 'private' keyword.

Comment: I use: `let downloadManager = DownloadManager()
                            downloadManager.id = self.id` and  DownloadManager :`var id = ""` But folder doesn't create.

Comment: Why you are assigning 'id' as empty string?

Comment: `var id = String()` but nothing to changes

Comment: That will initiate empty string to id. You need to assign the folder name to it.

Comment: I pass tableId in master controller but that I should write in DownloadManager. How to declare id?

Comment: @Artem i have updated the git project. DownloadManager to get folder path . pls check. https://github.com/mcabasheer/table-cell-progress-bar/tree/master